# get upcoming date record from mysql database, In codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an event management project, I need to get upcoming event from database, can anyone help me ?

I am using

```
SELECT *FROM  EVENTS WHERE  DATE_ADD(event_date, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(event_date) YEAR) 
        BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1;
```

But it gives me the event upcoming within 7 days only.
I should not want to provide days.

I want to get first upcoming event , doesn't matter after or within how many days it is coming.

thank you !

Comment: first of all please give more details on your table structure. What is 'upcoming event' column name? Just order that column desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a simple where clause comparing with current date

```
SELECT *
FROM  EVENTS 
WHERE  event_date > CURDATE()
ORDER BY event_date 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT * FROM  EVENTS WHERE event_date > CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: it will only ever get first event, need `where > today`

Comment: its working, thank you, before i was not considered the date present in database which are before today

Answer (score 1):

try

If column type `datetime` you can use `CURDATE()`(mysql function) or `date()`(php function)

```
"SELECT *FROM  EVENTS WHERE event_date > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' ORDER BY event_date  limit 1"
```

or

```
"SELECT *FROM  EVENTS WHERE event_date > CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date  limit 1"
```

If column type `date`

```
"SELECT *FROM  EVENTS WHERE event_date > '".date('Y-m-d')."' ORDER BY event_date  limit 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

try below it works perfectly fine

```
select * from table where start_time between NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

you can use like this to get next 7 days data or in case you want last 7 days then instead of DATE_ADD USE DATE_SUB It will work or you can use like

```
 start_time between NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

this also works. to know more check this ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone,

I got the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS 
WHERE event_date > CURDATE() 
ORDER BY event_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: its gives me upcoming event, try it.